# ARM template not populating app services configuration

Tags: azure, deployment, web-applications, azure-resource-manager, octopus

has anyone experienced using ARM templates to update or add Azure web app configurations and it does not update the configuration properly.
We use Octopus deploy to run our arm templates and deployments indicate to us that it is successful however the web app configurations arent updated or added.

is this a bug with arm templates? has anyone experienced this? what do you do you ensure webapp configurations are added or updated?
thanks

Comment: For webapp configurations using Octopus deploy, you can refer to [Deploy an Azure Resource Manager template using Octopus deploy](https://octopus.com/docs/runbooks/runbook-examples/azure/resource-groups) , [Azue webapp using Octopus deploy](https://octopus.com/docs/deployments/azure/deploying-a-package-to-an-azure-web-app),  and [octopusdeploy3-single-vm-windows](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/application-workloads/octopus/octopusdeploy3-single-vm-windows). If given references, does not solve your issue, you can ask here: https://help.octopus.com/

Answer (score 0):

As [DeepDave-MT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15969115/deepdave-mt) said, you can refer below links

1. https://octopus.com/docs/runbooks/runbook-examples/azure/resource-groups
2. https://octopus.com/docs/deployments/azure/deploying-a-package-to-an-azure-web-app
3. https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/application-workloads/octopus/octopusdeploy3-single-vm-windows